# C#, Triggering different events with timer.

Tags: c#, events, timer, triggers

I want to use a timer to trigger an event after 10 seconds of pressing a button, then trigger a different event automatically after 20 seconds, then have the timer stop after 30 seconds. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: either chain it or do the math

Comment: "then have the timer stop after 30 seconds" meaning what?

Answer (score 0):

Here we go (WPF):

```
async void OnButtonClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
    void OnCancel(object _, RoutedEventArgs __) => cts.Cancel();
    CancelButton.Click += OnCancel;

    try
    {
        await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2), cts.Token);

        // fire first event

        await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2), cts.Token);

        // fire second event

        await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2), cts.Token);

        // stop the timer (whatever it means)
    }
    catch (TaskCanceledException)
    {
        // handle cancelled
    }
    finally
    {
        CancelButton.Click -= OnCancel;
    }
}
```

Update: added cancelling.

Comment: Thank you, I would also like to add a cancel button which the user can press to cancel this entire operation. How can I do that?

Comment: Added cancelling.

Comment: After the first 'await', we're no longer assured to be running on the GUI thread, right? Might be worth a comment. Also, if we're working in WPF, we have the option of using WPF's timer class, but there seems little benefit in doing that (it doesn't invoke on the GUI thread so it's no help there). For the curious: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.windows.threading.dispatchertimer(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: We are assured to be running in the UI thread all the time here. await will schedule the rest of the function in the same synchronization context or task scheduler where it was in the previous part. Here we are in the context of the primary (UI) WPF thread, which has a task scheduler.